# MySQL GROUP BY within subquery by one or two cols and a WHERE clause outside of it explanation?

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

Today, after a period of pause from SQL, I came across the following query:

> There's an **orders** table:

```
CREATE TABLE `orders` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `order_type` char(2) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'C',
  `order_number` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `postal_code` char(5) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

> Each `order` has:

- an unique `id`;
- an `order_type` which can either be `C`, `S`, `R`,
  `RS`, `RR`, `RC` (it doesn't really matter what they mean, they are
  just used by the system internally);
- a `order_number` which is a code
  that represents a bill bound to the order (please note that one or
  more orders may be bound to the same `bill_number`, I know an INT
  column would be better, but I wasn't the one who created this table);
- and a `postal_code` which is a 5 char code for a zip code in my
  country (same as for `bill_number`, an INT column would be better, I
  know).

> Further, I have a `postal_codes` table:

```
CREATE TABLE `postal_codes` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `postal_code` char(5) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,     
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Now, what I needed to do was:

> Given a 5 char postal code, find its id together with the count of the bills bound to the orders which are of type `S`, `C` or `R`

Anyway, this is the query I came up with (for the `postal_code` -> `48890`):

```
SELECT b.id, COUNT(*) count
FROM (
   SELECT c.id, c.postal_code
   FROM (
      SELECT o.`postal_code` FROM `orders` o
      WHERE o.`order_type` IN ('S', 'C', 'R')
      AND o.`postal_code` IS NOT NULL AND o.`postal_code` NOT LIKE ''
      GROUP BY o.`order_number`, o.`postal_code`
   ) a
   JOIN `postal_codes` c
       ON a.`postal_code` = c.`postal_code`
   WHERE c.`postal_code` = "48890"
) b
GROUP BY b.id
```

Here is a Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3dee8/4

Now, it works like expected, the only thing to note is that inner most `GROUP BY`: I had to group by o.`order_number` first and then by `o.postal_code` because the following query I wrote before writing the one above:

```
SELECT b.id, COUNT(*) count
    FROM (
       SELECT c.id, c.postal_code
       FROM (
          SELECT o.`postal_code` FROM `orders` o
          WHERE o.`order_type` IN ('S', 'C', 'R')
          AND o.`postal_code` IS NOT NULL AND o.`postal_code` NOT LIKE ''
          GROUP BY o.`order_number`
       ) a
       JOIN `postal_codes` c
           ON a.`postal_code` = c.`postal_code`
       WHERE c.`postal_code` = "48890"
    ) b
    GROUP BY b.id
```

Sometimes didn't work as expected (I say `sometimes` because it seems that now it works with the fancy `Schema` I wrote in the fiddle, but sometimes a wrong `COUNT(*)` instead of the `COUNT(*)` returned by the query above was returned)

Could someone tell me what's the difference between the two queries (the first one with two `GROUP BY` columns in the inner most subquery which seems to work always for me and the second one with only one `GROUP_BY` column which sometimes works (as in this case, if I'll find out why, I will update this question) and sometimes doesn't and returns a wrong `COUNT(*)`)? Why the use of two columns in a GROUP BY always ensures that the correct final `COUNT(*)` is returned and the use of one column doesn't?

I am a bit confused.

Thanks for the attention.

UPDATE: The Fiddle I posted seems not to work, anyway, here is the SQL code for the example schema I used:

```
-- SQL Fiddle Build Schema
    CREATE TABLE `orders` (
      `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `order_type` char(2) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'C',
      `order_number` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
      `postal_code` char(5) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
    ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

CREATE TABLE `postal_codes` (
      `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `postal_code` char(5) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
    ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

INSERT INTO orders (order_type, order_number, postal_code) VALUES ("S", "192010NJDOS", "48890");
INSERT INTO orders (order_type, order_number, postal_code) VALUES ("C", "192010NJDOS", "48890");
INSERT INTO orders (order_type, order_number, postal_code) VALUES ("R", "192010NJDOS", "48890");
INSERT INTO orders (order_type, order_number, postal_code) VALUES ("S", "129019302KS", "48890");
INSERT INTO orders (order_type, order_number, postal_code) VALUES ("C", "129019302KS", "48890");
INSERT INTO orders (order_type, order_number, postal_code) VALUES ("C", "4444HHJSKAA", "48890");
INSERT INTO orders (order_type, order_number, postal_code) VALUES ("C", "4444HHJSKAA", "48890");
INSERT INTO orders (order_type, order_number, postal_code) VALUES ("S", "4444HHJSKAA", "48890");
INSERT INTO orders (order_type, order_number, postal_code) VALUES ("S", "4444HHJSKAA", "48890");
INSERT INTO orders (order_type, order_number, postal_code) VALUES ("S", "11111AAAAAA", "48890");
INSERT INTO orders (order_type, order_number, postal_code) VALUES ("C", "BBBBB222222", "48890");
INSERT INTO orders (order_type, order_number, postal_code) VALUES ("R", "FFFFFFFK933", "48890");
INSERT INTO orders (order_type, order_number, postal_code) VALUES ("RC", "777777SSSSS", "48890");
INSERT INTO orders (order_type, order_number, postal_code) VALUES ("RS", "777877SSSSS", "48890");
INSERT INTO orders (order_type, order_number, postal_code) VALUES ("RR", "779977SSSSS", "48890");

INSERT INTO orders (order_type, order_number, postal_code) VALUES ("S", "88818999999", "65889");
INSERT INTO orders (order_type, order_number, postal_code) VALUES ("C", "88818999999", "65889");
INSERT INTO orders (order_type, order_number, postal_code) VALUES ("R", "88818999999", "65889");
INSERT INTO orders (order_type, order_number, postal_code) VALUES ("S", "7777JJJJJJJ", "65889");
INSERT INTO orders (order_type, order_number, postal_code) VALUES ("C", "AJSJ8888LLL", "65889");
INSERT INTO orders (order_type, order_number, postal_code) VALUES ("RC", "AJSJ888899L", "65889");
INSERT INTO orders (order_type, order_number, postal_code) VALUES ("RC", "AJSJ888899L", "65889");
INSERT INTO orders (order_type, order_number, postal_code) VALUES ("RS", "AJSJ888899L", "65889");
INSERT INTO orders (order_type, order_number, postal_code) VALUES ("RR", "AJS7788899L", "65889");
INSERT INTO orders (order_type, order_number, postal_code) VALUES ("RR", "AMMMM88899L", "65889");

INSERT INTO orders (order_type, order_number, postal_code) VALUES ("S", "00001020202", "12033");
INSERT INTO orders (order_type, order_number, postal_code) VALUES ("C", "00001020202", "12033");
INSERT INTO orders (order_type, order_number, postal_code) VALUES ("R", "KKKKKKKKSK2", "12033");
INSERT INTO orders (order_type, order_number, postal_code) VALUES ("S", "KKKKKKKKSK2", "12033");
INSERT INTO orders (order_type, order_number, postal_code) VALUES ("C", "KKKKKKKKSK2", "12033");
INSERT INTO orders (order_type, order_number, postal_code) VALUES ("RC", "DKSKOKDOKOK", "12033");
INSERT INTO orders (order_type, order_number, postal_code) VALUES ("RS", "KKKKKKKKSK2", "12033");
INSERT INTO orders (order_type, order_number, postal_code) VALUES ("RR", "KKKKKK99999", "12033");
-- ---
INSERT INTO postal_codes (postal_code) VALUES ("48890");
INSERT INTO postal_codes (postal_code) VALUES ("65889");
INSERT INTO postal_codes (postal_code) VALUES ("12033");

-- SQL Fiddle 
 SELECT b.id, COUNT(*) count
        FROM (
           SELECT c.id, c.postal_code
           FROM (
              SELECT o.`postal_code` FROM `orders` o
              WHERE o.`order_type` IN ('S', 'C', 'R')
              AND o.`postal_code` IS NOT NULL AND o.`postal_code` NOT LIKE ''
              GROUP BY o.`order_number`
           ) a
           JOIN `postal_codes` c
               ON a.`postal_code` = c.`postal_code`
           WHERE c.`postal_code` = "48890"
        ) b
        GROUP BY b.id
```

Answer (score 2):

Your query seems way to complicated.  Here is one way to express it:

```
  SELECT p.postal_code, p.id, count(*)
  FROM `orders` o JOIN
       postalcodes p
       ON o.postal_code = p.postal_code
  WHERE o.`order_type` IN ('S', 'C', 'R') AND
        p.postal_code = $Postal_Code
  GROUP BY p.postal_code, p.id;
```

Note that strictly speaking, the `GROUP BY` is unnecessary, but it is useful if you want the values for more than one postal code.

As another note, the data structure is a bit messed up.  The postal code in `Orders` should be to the primary key `id` rather than to the postal code.

EDIT:

To get a count of zero, you can do:

```
  SELECT p.postal_code, p.id, count(o.postal_code)
  FROM postalcodes p left join
       orders o
       ON o.postal_code = p.postal_code and
          o.order_type IN ('S', 'C', 'R')
  WHERE p.postal_code = $Postal_Code
  GROUP BY p.postal_code, p.id;
```

Comment: Perhaps it would be useful to use an outer join (and make other minor adjustments), so as to return a row when there are no orders for the given postal code.  Also, if `postal_code` values can be assumed unique in table `postal_codes` then the `GROUP BY` can be eliminated.

Comment: Thanks for the response, `...strictly speaking, the GROUP BY is unnecessary, but it is useful if you want the values for more than one postal code`, yes, that was the next step, show a postal code `id` together with its number of `bills` **not orders**, as you se in the queries I posted, I group by `order_number` and COUNT that result, not the orders, cause more than one order can appear in one bill (`order_number`) and in this case it should be counted only once. But what's the difference of using a `GROUP BY` by one column and a `GROUP BY` by two, how MySQL logic changes in such cases?

Comment: And yes `As another note, the data structure is a bit messed up. The postal code in Orders should be to the primary key id rather than to the postal code`, I agree with you, but as I sad I wasn't the one who created the tables.